# How to set google chrome to don't load tabs until selected?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have set my google chrome's on startup settings to **continue where you left off**
[image]

And whenever I start my chrome all tabs start to load as soon as they get opened which causes me problems and suppose if there is a youtube page in the tabs then I get a lot off attention of people :P

Can I make it like FireFox which provides the same feature "Continue where your left off" but tabs do't starts to laod automaticaly and only the page which is selected gets loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe Chrome has this function, but there is an extension you can download that might help you, The Great Suspender.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg

Comment: Taht one worked until i removed it and it made grablegarbled links witch wont load anymore. Well Firefox has this functionallity and in options in firefox choose this option not loading until selected. Also firefox is 64 bit on Linux and Windows but Mac is very vulnerable so no more new programms for mac. And Chrome i just dont use until i want to test something new witch Google is pressuring with to use Chrome. So only for Google- thanks no.

Answer (score -1):

I found one extension that work like firefox, footab, others suspend tabs after a given time not at start. I've tried the great suspender and tab suspender.

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit? The accepted answer isn't an optimum model to follow, but it at least includes a link.  Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.